# Terminal and software center missing

Tags: 13.04, software-center, virtualbox, gnome-terminal

I cannot find either the Ubuntu Software center or the terminal anywhere on my computer. I downloaded virtualbox from their website and after it started applying changes in the software center the software center closed and disappeared along with the terminal. Those are the only ones I have noticed but there might be others missing too.

Message from `sudo apt-get check`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: Try Ctrl + Alt + T for the terminal. Alt + F2 then type software-center for the USC. I would recommend you to install debsums to check your installation, with the terminal `sudo apt-get install debsums && debsums -s`.

Comment: crtl + alt + t wont bring up the terminal. Its as if its uninstalled.

Comment: Alt + F2 then typing gnome-terminal should also work. Please test everything then answer back.

Comment: command not found for both instances.

Comment: Can you press Alt + F2 then type `xterm`?

Comment: yeah, i got that.

Comment: Can you do `sudo apt-get check` copy the output, edit your question and paste it? Do not use the comments (this are called comments).

Comment: Same thing just happened to me after installing VirtualBox on 13.10. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Run `xterm` from your dash and install gnome-terminal and USC again:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal

sudo apt-get install software-cente
```

If you don't have xterm then swtich to one of your virtual consoles tty's using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd> or f2..6

Then run the same commands above after your login with your username and password.